# Reference stored in Struct does not live long enough for closure

Tags: struct, rust, reference, closures, lifetime

I'm holding a reference to a Struct inside another Struct, both of which are declared in the same block.
I later want to use the outer Struct in a closure which is run repeatedly and never returns.
The reference inside the Struct apparently does not live long enough, but in my understanding, it should never go out of scope, or at least should live at least as long as the Struct it is referring to:

```
struct MyStruct;

struct ReferenceStruct<'a> {
    reference: &'a MyStruct
}

impl<'a> ReferenceStruct<'a> {
    fn do_something(&self) -> () {}
}

fn run<F>(mut function: F) -> !
where
    F: FnMut() -> () + 'static
{
    loop {
        function();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let my_struct = MyStruct;
    let reference = ReferenceStruct { reference: &my_struct };

    run(move || {
        reference.do_something();
    });
}
```

([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f1cf309b40c958480464174abd0d0487))

The **run** function (for context) mirrors an event loop, similar to that of Winit, and in reality, I have another Struct which owns the value being referenced, but this example reproduces it in fewer lines.

The error:

```
error[E0597]: `my_struct` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:26:50
   |
26 |       let reference = ReferenceStruct { reference: &my_struct };
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
27 | 
28 | /     run(move ||
29 | |     {
30 | |         reference.do_something();
31 | |     });
   | |______- argument requires that `my_struct` is borrowed for `'static`
32 |   }
   |   - `my_struct` dropped here while still borrowed
```

It appears that **my_struct** is dropped at the end of **main**, but even if the program flow somehow escapes the loop, it surely lasts as long as the **reference** struct, which is as long as it needs to.  I don't understand where or how this error *could* come about, or what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the lifetime bound `'static` for the closure passed into `run()`. This means that the lifetime of `reference` is also `'static` because it is moved into the closure, which in turn means that `my_struct` must also have static lifetime – and that is not the case.

Luckily, you do not need the `'static` bound here. If you remove it, everything works:

```rust
...
fn run<F>(mut function: F) -> !
where
    F: FnMut() -> ()
...
```

However, this might not be a solution in your use case if the event loop needs the closure to be `'static`.

Comment: This works perfectly for my example.  Unfortunately, the closure is required to last for 'static (run method on winit::event_loop::EventLoop) which I did not realise when posting.  When I remove the 'static lifetime in my code, I am told that the passed function may not last long enough.  Thank you for this answer though, and my understanding has been improved.

Comment: Yeah, looks like `'static` is indeed required by winit because some platforms destroy the stack before the closure is executed according to [this Github issue](https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/issues/1543#issuecomment-616833377). You might be able to use [`run_return()`](https://docs.rs/winit/0.25.0/winit/platform/run_return/trait.EventLoopExtRunReturn.html#tymethod.run_return), but please check the docs, seems like this also has some drawbacks. Sadly, I'm not familiar with winit, so I am not of much help here.

Comment: This method works great for me, as it does not matter whether the control flow is returned, and I can indeed send a 'normal' closure.  Thank you very much :D